# Problem with skyrim!

Tags: 12.04, wine, games, steam

[UBUNTU 12.04LTS] When I try to launch Skyrim via Steam with Wine, it wants to install DirectX 10, Then it launches game, or if we are more specific, error screens saying it hitted critical problem. This is full error report:

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function msvcp90.dll.??0?$basic_ifstream@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@QAE@PB_WHH@Z called in 32-bit code (0x7b839cf2).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b839cf2 ESP:0033f7a0 EBP:0033f804 EFLAGS:00200246(   - --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:7b826245 EBX:7b894ff4 ECX:00000000 EDX:80000100
 ESI:80000100 EDI:00429ef0
Stack dump:
0x0033f7a0:  0033f824 00000008 0041db3c 80000100
0x0033f7b0:  00000001 00000000 7b839cf2 00000002
0x0033f7c0:  7e449340 7e44c992 00000004 7e46f550
0x0033f7d0:  0041db3c 0033f8bc 0033f7ec 00403e52
0x0033f7e0:  00000001 00000000 0013e8b8 0033f81c
0x0033f7f0:  00403059 0033fb18 7b839caa 00000000
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 16-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b839cf2 in kernel32 (+0x29cf2) (0x0033f804)
  1 0x7e4492a8 in msvcp90 (+0x392a7) (0x0033f834)
  2 0x7e414825 in msvcp90 (+0x4824) (0x0033fd38)
  3 0x0040a040 in skyrimlauncher (+0xa03f) (0x0033fd38)
  4 0x00412633 in skyrimlauncher (+0x12632) (0x0033fde0)
  5 0x00407acf in skyrimlauncher (+0x7ace) (0x0033fe70)
  6 0x7b859cdc call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe88)
  7 0x7b85af4f in kernel32 (+0x4af4e) (0x0033fec8)
  8 0x7bc71db0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fed8)
  9 0x7bc7486d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  10 0x7bc71d8e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  11 0x7bc49f4e call_dll_entry_point+0x61d() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
0x7b839cf2: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (94 modules)
PE    400000-  5d2000   Export          skyrimlauncher
PE  10000000-100a3000   Deferred        gameoverlayrenderer
PE  3b400000-3b41e000   Deferred        steam_api
ELF 7b800000-7ba15000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba15000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcc3000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d676000-7d67f000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d67f000-7d684000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d684000-7d69c000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d69c000-7d6a0000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7d6a0000-7d6e9000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d6e9000-7d6fb000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d6fb000-7d780000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d780000-7d792000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d792000-7d79b000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d79b000-7d7a0000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7d7a0000-7d7c8000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d7c8000-7d897000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d897000-7d8a9000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d8a9000-7d8b7000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7d8b7000-7d97b000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d97b000-7d9b9000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d9b9000-7da0c000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7dddd000-7de11000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7dde0000-7de11000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7de11000-7de17000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7de17000-7de22000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7de24000-7de38000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7de30000-7de38000   \               psapi
ELF 7de94000-7debe000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7debe000-7def2000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7def2000-7df02000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7df02000-7df23000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7df23000-7df29000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7df29000-7df43000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 7df43000-7e077000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e077000-7e089000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e089000-7e092000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 7e093000-7e097000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e097000-7e0a0000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e0a0000-7e0aa000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e0aa000-7e13d000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e0b0000-7e13d000   \               winex11
ELF 7e13d000-7e153000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e153000-7e1ed000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e1ed000-7e20f000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e1f0000-7e20f000   \               imm32
ELF 7e20f000-7e237000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e210000-7e237000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e237000-7e2e4000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e240000-7e2e4000   \               winmm
ELF 7e2e4000-7e327000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7e2f0000-7e327000   \               dsound
ELF 7e327000-7e356000   Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE  7e330000-7e356000   \               msvcr90
ELF 7e356000-7e3e3000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e3e3000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e3e3000-7e4c8000   Dwarf           msvcp90<elf>
  \-PE  7e410000-7e4c8000   \               msvcp90
ELF 7e4c8000-7e53d000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e4d0000-7e53d000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e53d000-7e645000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e550000-7e645000   \               ole32
ELF 7e645000-7e73d000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e650000-7e73d000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e73d000-7e756000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e740000-7e756000   \               version
ELF 7e756000-7e813000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e760000-7e813000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e813000-7e953000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e820000-7e953000   \               user32
ELF 7e953000-7e9bd000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e960000-7e9bd000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e9bd000-7ebce000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9d0000-7ebce000   \               shell32
ELF 7ebce000-7ec2e000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ebe0000-7ec2e000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ec4f000-7ec69000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ec69000-7ec72000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efbc000-7efe8000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efed000-7eff3000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7eff3000-7f000000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF f7484000-f7488000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f7489000-f748e000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f748e000-f7637000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7638000-f7653000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7654000-f765b000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF f765b000-f765f000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f765f000-f766b000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF f766b000-f77ad000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77af000-f77d1000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77d1000-f77d2000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000007f    0
    0000007e    0
    0000001f    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000021    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    00000023    0
0000003f Agent.exe
    00000049    0
    00000048    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003e    0
    00000041    0
    00000025    0
    00000031    0
    0000002c    0
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    0000002d    0
    00000040    0
0000005f Steam.exe
    00000039    0
    00000052    0
    000000a1    0
    000000a2    0
    000000c2    0
    00000047    0
    00000056    0
    0000004f    0
    0000000d    0
    0000000b    0
    00000017    0
    00000054    0
    0000005b    0
    00000036    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005a    0
    00000043    0
    00000032    0
    00000051    0
    0000004b    0
    00000035    0
    00000064    0
    00000057    0
    00000046    0
    00000062    0
    00000063    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    0000003d    0
    00000060    0
    00000034    0
    0000004d    0
    00000019    0
    00000055    0
    00000061    0
    00000026    0
    0000005c    0
    00000009    0
    00000059    0
    0000002a    0
    0000004a    0
    00000038    0
    00000045    0
    00000018    0
    00000042    0
    0000005d    0
0000007b svchost.exe
    00000093    0
    00000085    0
    00000084    0
    00000082    0
    00000081    0
    0000007d    0
    0000007c    0
000000a6 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Skyrim\SkyrimLauncher.exe
    000000a5    0 <==

System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.4
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.5.0-39-generic
```

Comment: Seems offtopic to me: this is a bug in a wine game. It would be better to ask this on the wineHQ forums here: http://forum.winehq.org/viewforum.php?f=8  To me this "Unhandled exception: unimplemented function" means your installer is not correct. And while I am at it: http://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15105 and http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=29420 seems to answer your problem.

Comment: Close-voters: This does not appear to be a bug or otherwise off-topic. See [Oli's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/338791/22949).

Answer (score 3):

Looks suspiciously like you haven't followed [the instructions on AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=24749).

> Running game for 1.3.32:
>   winetricks d3dx9_42 vcrun2008 xact
>   Remove Intro video in "Skyrim/Data/Video"
>   If using pulseaudio set Win7 mode.

You need an "original" msvcp90.dll. You can't use the Wine-provided version. That's provided by vcrun2008.